# C++ changing const variable through pointers

Tags: c++, constants

I am a regular java developer, but now my new job requires me to learn C++. I am following a course on modern C++ and she showed me various things that the compiler will catch if we are modifying const variable through indirection. But I have worked in my college days on C and from that, I know you could write something to surpass this check. I wrote the below code and the debugger is working as expected by me which means I am able to successfully modify the const value but for some reason the value printed or any operation performed on the const is still using the original value of the const even when the debugger is showing the current value to be something else.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int const i = 3;
    _int64 abc = (_int64) &i;

    int* p = (int*)abc;
    (*p)++;
    int k = i + 1;
    std::cout << "value of i and k " << i << " " << k;

    return 0;

}
```

Output

> value of i and k 3 4

Can someone explain this to me, what magic is happening behind this?

Comment: Changing a variable declared `const` like you do makes your program have undefined behavior. I'm not sure what you hope to learn here. Don't change variables declared `const`

Comment: *"what magic is happening behind this?"* Black magic of UB.

Comment: The compiler knows `i` is `const` and so can't be changed. So it optimises out the `std::cout << "value of i and k " << i << " " << k;` call with `i` set to 3. The compiler is allowed to assume there is no undefined behaviour in your code - that's where all the contradictions you observe stem from.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I know this is something which we will never do, while you call this an undefined behavior. The behavior is pretty consistent its doing the same thing again and again. So there has to be a definition to this thing, i wanted to understand the thing happening here.

Comment: It is not consistent. Changing compilers, compiler version, small bits of code, the phase of the moon all can and eventually _will_ change it. Undefined behavoir is undefined. Just dont rely on it.

Comment: @MikeVine will never use such ugly code anywhere, its just conceptually i needed an answer i got my answer above to the question that was there in my head. Due to compiler optimization the value of i is not even looked at while printing or using the variable i so my edits to the variable are not reflected.

Comment: Your compiler is free to do whatever in this case. It could store `3` in a register and it doesn't need to read the the memory where `3` is stored to print `i` since it's `const` so nothing is supposed to change it. You could also simplify the code a bit to not have to involve `reinterpret_cast` to `int64`: https://godbolt.org/z/WTov4eq6f

Comment: @TedLyngmo oops, I mentally added an & somewhere